# Testing wrapper class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I would like to test a class that is used as a wrapper that provides abstraction for the classes underneath.

That means that I need to create some objects inside that class, that is, I don't pass collaborators through constructor or some method.

For example, here's a wrapper class:

```
public class Abstraction {

      private ComplexClass complex;

      public class Abstraction(some parameters) {
           complex = new Complex(parameters);
      }

}
```

To be able to test this class I had an idea to create a method that will return an object of Complex class, like this:

```
public class Abstraction {

      private ComplexClass complex;

      public class Abstraction(parameters) {
           complex = createComplex(parameters);
      }

      protected createComplex ComplexClass(parameters) {
           return new ComplexClass(parameters);
      }
}
```

The thing is, I cannot use Mockito to mock collaborators created inside constructor of class that I'm testing. How to overcome this?

My idea was to spy the SUT so that createComplex returns mock object, but I cannot do that because SUT needs to be created first. It's kind of a dead lock.

My final goal is to test whether some methods of collaborator classes were called.

Answer (score 2):

What is the business advantage of testing this class? It doesn't implement an algorithm and it doesn't make a decision. As you say, it is only a wrapper.

You say that you want to test if certain methods are called but how does that help anybody? Surely a test that confirms that the methods were called in some situations and not others, in other words a test of the business logic, would be much more useful. The risk here is that you will end up with a complex test that is difficult to maintain and introduces inertia that will make future re-factoring much more difficult and expensive. What is the reward you are hoping foir that will make that risk worthwhile?

Comment: I'm actually not very experienced with testing, I'm still learning, so I'm open to comments such as yours. So what would you recommend then, not to test it at all?

Comment: A good test proves that some code behaves the way it should. If the code is simple and obvious, (or doesn't do anything) then it doesn't need testing.

Comment: +1 here.  The only possible reason for testing this kind of class is that  you have an incompetent manager who insists on a certain code coverage percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a reasonably simple anonymous inner class in your test case

```
ComplexClass mock = Mockito.mock(ComplexClass.class);
Abstraction abstraction = new Abstraction("foo") {
    @Override
    protected ComplexClass createComplex(parameters) {
       return mock;
    }
};
assertTrue("bar", abstraction.doStuff());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#Java_Example) for your `ComplexClass` which you set on your `Abstraction`:

```
public class ComplexClassFactory {
    public ComplexClass create(parameters) {
        return new ComplexClass(parameters);
    }
}

public class Abstraction {

    private ComplexClassFactory complexClassFactory; 

    public void setComplexClassFactory(ComplexClassFactory complexClassFactory) {
        this.complexClassFactory = complexClassFactory;
    }

    private ComplexClass complex;

    public class Abstraction(parameters) {
       complex = complexClassFactory.create(parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to extract an interface for the `ComplexClass` class (which I named `Complex`) and provide an alternate constructor used *only for testing purposes* to inject an instance of the newly created `Complex` interface:

```
    public class Abstraction {

        private Complex complex;

        public Abstraction(String parameters) {
            this.complex = new ComplexClass(parameters);
        }

        Abstraction(Complex complex) {
            this.complex = complex;
        }

        public class ComplexClass implements Complex {

            private final String parameters;

            public ComplexClass(String parameters) {
                this.parameters = parameters;
            }
        }

        interface Complex {
        }

    }
```

This way you can create a mock for the `Complex` interface, use the constructor which receives a `Complex` instance and test the *Abstraction* class independently:

```
@Test
public void testAbstraction() {
    Complex mock = Mockito.mock(Complex.class);
    Abstraction abstraction = new Abstraction(mock);
}
```